# Terminal OSX: The "string" command requires the command line developer tools

Tags: objective-c, terminal

I need to get the manufacturers of the screen/display from `objective-c`

in order to achieve it, I am running a terminal command from `obj-c` and parsing its output.

**Command**

```
ioreg -lw0 | grep "EDID" | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r | strings -6
```

Its working fine on my system but when I am running the same command either from my code or from the `Terminal` on a user's system, it's showing a prompt asking me to download some developer tools which is not possible for me to do on all user's systems.

**Screenshot of the prompt:**

[image]

**Command result on my terminal**

```
n:~ user$ ioreg -lw0 | grep "EDID" | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r | strings -6 
P .00 6 LP133WX3-TLA3 Color LCD n:~ user$
```

**I am using the given below code to execute terminal command**

```
-(NSString*)runCommand:(NSString*)commandToRun;
{
    NSString *output=@"";

    @autoreleasepool {
    NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];

    NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"-c" ,
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", commandToRun],
                          nil];
    NSLog(@"run command: %@",commandToRun);
    [task setArguments: arguments];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    NSPipe *errorPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardError:errorPipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    NSFileHandle *errorFile;
    errorFile = [errorPipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSData* errorData;
    errorData = [errorFile readDataToEndOfFile];


    output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *errorOutput;
    errorOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: errorData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    }

    return output;
}
```

Please suggest something like an alternative of the command or any workaround.

Many thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really, best option is to use `ioreg -lw0 | grep "EDID" | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r` send it to your main mac and then filter it locally with `strings -6`.

EDIT: After your details in the comments your should :
Run on their Mac `ioreg -lw0 | grep "EDID" | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r > ~/Desktop/report.txt` tell them to send the file you. Say you received it on desktop, then run `strings -6 ~/Desktop/report.txt` on your local machine.

Comment: `filter it locally with strings -6` could you please elaborate @daredevil

Comment: how are you sending the above command to the remote computers ?

Comment: actually, I have created an application (code provided in the question) . Users are running the app on their mac books and the application is capturing their system information.

Comment: Then you should run `ioreg -lw0 | grep "EDID" | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r > ~/Desktop/report.txt` tell them to send the file you. Say you received it on desktop, then run `strings -6 ~/Desktop/report.txt` on your local machine.

Comment: I did as you said but when I am running `strings -6 ~/Desktop/report.txt` terminal is again showing the prompt and saying `xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.`

Comment: Can't you install the command line tools on your machine ? Not on the client machine on which you run `ioreg -lw0 | grep "EDID" | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r > ~/Desktop/report.txt`